# Liferay: how to get the current login user details in servlet?

Tags: servlets, liferay-6, orbeon

I'm completely new to Liferay. I have configured **Orbeon Forms** in Liferay by using the **Proxy Portlet**, finally I created an Orbeon form and sent the form data to a demo portlet (custom portlet). In the portlet I have created a servlet. If user save the orbeon form data then my servlet getting called and I'm able to get the form data. Now I need to get the current user name or userid in the servlet.

In form builder I have send the orbeon form data to my servlet.

**properties-local.xml**

```
    <property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*"
  value='require-valid
         then send(uri = "http://localhost:9090/FRunner-portlet/html/jsp/formData.jsp?username={xxf:get-request-header('Orbeon-Username')}", method="POST", content="metadata")
                 then success-message("save-success")
                 recover error-message("database-error")'/>
```

If I tried the above code I got the following errors,

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException: line 80, column 122 of oxf:/config/properties-local.xml: Fatal error: Element type "property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener$$anonfun$contextInitialized$2.apply(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:39)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener$$anonfun$contextInitialized$2.apply(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:39)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$.withRootException(ScalaUtils.scala:87)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener.contextInitialized(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:39)


Caused by: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException: line 80, column 122 of oxf:/config/properties-local.xml: Fatal error: Element type "property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
        at org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLParsing$ErrorHandler.fatalError(XMLParsing.java:215)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)


SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener$$anonfun$contextDestroyed$2.apply(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:44)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener$$anonfun$contextDestroyed$2.apply(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:44)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$.withRootException(ScalaUtils.scala:87)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(OrbeonServletContextListener.scala:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4819)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5466)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.InitUtils$.org$orbeon$oxf$pipeline$InitUtils$$fromProperty$1(InitUtils.scala:195)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.InitUtils$.processorDefinitions$lzycompute(InitUtils.scala:196)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.InitUtils$.processorDefinitions(InitUtils.scala:179)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.Orbeon$.initialize(Orbeon.scala:84)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonWebApp$$anonfun$1.apply(WebAppContext.scala:117)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonWebApp$$anonfun$1.apply(WebAppContext.scala:117)
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:189)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ParametersAndAttributes$$anon$1.getOrElseUpdate(WebAppContext.scala:93)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonWebApp$class.$init$(WebAppContext.scala:117)
```

**Update**

```
xxf:get-request-header('orbeon-liferay-user-email')
```

**With the above statement I am able to get the liferay login user mail id. Now I need to pass this username to my portlet as a parameter. Can you please let me know what is the procedure to pass the mailid to my portlet. I tried in different ways but it is not happen. Please suggest me something to send the liferay user mail id to my portlet.**

**FormData Servlet code**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();                        
    try {                       
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (request.getInputStream());
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
           int value;
           while ((value=in.read()) != -1) {
               buffer.append((char)value);
            }
           String formData =  buffer.toString();
           System.out.println("Form Data==========>"+ formData);
    } catch (Exception e) {                   
      System.out.println("ERROR2=====>"+e);
    }                                             
}
```

How to get the current user details when servlet getting called?

Comment: You use a `DataInputStream` in your code above, and that is most certainly wrong. To retrieve the XML body posted by Orbeon Forms as text, you can use `new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8")` and read from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to explicitly pass it to the URL of the `send` action, for example:

```
uri = ".../FormData?username={xxf:get-request-header('Orbeon-Username')}"
```

In Orbeon Forms 4.9, there is a new [`xxf:username()`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/XForms-~-XPath-Function-Library#xxfusername) function which is more direct.

On the servlet side, you can retrieve a URL parameter using:

```
request.getParameter("username")
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested. I got error which have updated in my question. Please suggest some solution

Comment: Regarding the error: there was clearly a syntax error. Make sure you check your `properties-local.xml` at line 80.

Comment: I updated the answer. If you pass a `username` parameter, you can retrieve it with `request.getParameter`.

Comment: @ ebruchez,If it possible to get the form id in my servlet?

Comment: Yes, the parameter name is called `document`. You can see all parameters passed [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes#url-format).