# Orbeon - Is it possible to specify headers on a 'send' action?

Tags: orbeon

When using the header driven authorization method for authentication, for example, is it possible to forward the User Id or other headers when using send to call a service?

In my specific case, I plan to use a portlet filter with the Proxy Portlet. That will forward an Authorization header to Form Runner [as described here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Portal-~-Liferay-Proxy-Portlet-Guide#configuring-header-and-url-parameter-forwarding).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746692/liferay-how-to-get-the-current-login-user-details-in-servlet/29760871#29760871) describes how to include a header as a request parameter, but I would like to include it as a header.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `oxf.http.forward-headers` property:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.http.forward-headers"
    value="My-Header-1 My-Header-2"/>
```

Comment: I thought I got a successful test with this, but it looks like I was mistaken. The Authorization header is sent to the Authorization Service, but is not sent when using `send`. Is there any other way to do this?